# Sorted Key/Value Database solution

Tags: database, redis, key-value-store

I'm looking to implement a database solution to support very fast column based access on a set of simple 2D datasets. i.e consider this dataset

```
==========================================================
                     SOME DATASET1
==========================================================
   ENTRY     |    Col1   |   Col2  |    Col3    ... Coln
----------------------------------------------------------
   ENTRY A        1.1        0.2         5.5       6.2
   ENTRY B        2.3        6.4         1.5       1.1
   ENTRY C        2.2        4.2         9.5       3.4
   ENTRY D        2.3        1.1         5.5       2.9
   ENTRY E        9.1        3.6         7.5       2.6
```

What I need is a means of simply selecting all values in column1, or column2, or column n, while preserving the sort order. My initial idea was to use redis, with the following keyspace design:

```
   SOMEDS1/COLUMNS/           =>     Col1, Col2, Col3 ... Coln
   SOMEDS1/ENTRIES/           =>     A, B, C, D, E
   SOMEDS1/Col1/              =>     1.1, 2.3, 2.2, 2.3, 9.1
   SOMEDS1/Coln/              =>     ......
```

The principle behind this design is that the number of entries in each list are not large, perhaps < 10,000 but there may be a lots of columns, and only selected columns are ever needed at a given time.

My question is has anyone implemented anything like this already, and if so can you advice on the most appopriate type of database. My initial thoughts were to go with redis but I'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not specify if you need local or remote access to your data store. If you need remote access, then Redis is probably a very good solution. If your access is purely local, an embedded database (such as BerkeleyDB) will probably be more efficient.

The main point is to define how the data are maintained: can new entries only be added at the end of the data structure or not? If yes, Redis lists will fly to store your columns. If not, keeping your data unsorted in a hash object (associated entry and value) per column is probably better. If the number of entries is low, sorting the data after retrieval on client side is cheap anyway.

This design is similar to the implementation you can find in some columnar databases. The main benefit of this approach is the system can compress the values for a given column with a high-compression ratio, which is interesting when the volume of data is large. The downside is real-time maintenance of the data is difficult. For examples with MySQL, you may want to have a look at [Infobright](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infobright) or [Calpont](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calpont) products.

In your case, if the volume of data is limited, Redis is a good fit. But please note the representation of these data in memory will not be especially compact (involving pointers, double-linked lists and/or hash-tables) when the number of entries becomes significant (i.e. more than the thresholds described [here](http://redis.io/topics/memory-optimization)).

Comment: Sorry, forgot to say that data is accessed remotely.
Also data properties are not always known in advance which is why I'm not looking at classic'column store' solutions. This design would give me the flexibility of quick access to specific columns, wihtout knowing the columns in advance. I take you're point about column compression, but partitioned fast access is more important for the solution, which again is why this design was chosen. Do you know the effects of setting vm-max-memory to 0 and using it as a disk DB (with keys in memory?)

Comment: The VM implementation is deprecated. It has disappeared in 2.6. Redis is now a pure in-memory store (with optional disk snapshotting or journalization). VM management did not fit well in Redis model (single-threaded event loop).

Comment: Ah, I see. That may be a no go for this solution then. I cannot afford to load all the data in memory, there will be far too much of it. Do you know if MongoDB/CouchDb would be a better fit for key:SomeVal and Value:A list of entries.

Comment: You can probably do it with MongoDB, by having a collection containing documents (one per column), each of them containing an array. Please note the size of a documents in MongoDB is limited to 16 MB.

Comment: Hmm... 16MB is far too small. I've looked at GridFS as well, but it doesn't seem to support querying of the actual data. It just splits it up into chunks and lets you save/retrieve it. Is there any database you're aware of that is desinged to store sets of ordered lists?

Comment: If you only have 10000 entries per list, each list should easily fit in 16 MB ... In a MongoDB array, each floating point item will take 12 bytes, so you can put more than 1M of them for each column ...

Comment: I have around 10000 entries per list, but each entry can have around 40-ish related columns which I think would then give a document size of 4.8MB. So in theory this solution should scale to about 4 times the size of my current datasets. Sounds like a very viable option.

Answer (score 1):

I store data in Redis like this:

Strings:

```
Entry:A:Col1 => 1.1
Entry:A:Col2 => 0.2
Entry:A:Col3 => 5.5
...
Entry:A:ColN => 6.2
```

You can use infinite number of columns (limited by physical memory)